# How do I change the text color of a SwiftUI swipeAction button?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-swipeactions

I have a swipeAction in my SwiftUI list and I can't seem to change the color of the text.  It is always white.

```
.swipeActions(edge: HorizontalEdge.leading, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
    Button {
            
    } label: {
        Text("July 3rd")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
    .tint(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
}
```

I've tried to set the button to PlainButtonStyle() but that also didn't work

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You could build custom Swipe Actions instead.

Comment: It wasn't possible in UIKit, either.